# Splitting a numpy array / pandas dataframe by boolean delimiters

Tags: pandas, numpy

Assume a numpy array (actually Pandas) of the form:

```
[value, included,
 0.123, False,
 0.127, True,
 0.140, True,
 0.111, False,
 0.159, True,
 0.321, True,
 0.444, True,
 0.323, True,
 0.432, False]
```

I'd like to split the array such that `False` elements are excluded and successive runs of `True` elements are split into their own array.  So for the above case, we'd end up with:

```
[[0.127, True,
  0.140, True],
 [0.159, True,
  0.321, True,
  0.444, True,
  0.323, True]]
```

I can certainly do this by pushing individual elements onto lists, but surely there must be a more numpy-ish way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can create groups by inverse mask by `~` with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and filter only `True`s by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then create list of `DataFrame`s by [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
dfs = [v for k, v in df.groupby((~df['included']).cumsum()[df['included']])]
print (dfs)
[   value  included
1  0.127      True
2  0.140      True,    value  included
4  0.159      True
5  0.321      True
6  0.444      True
7  0.323      True]
```

Also is possible convert Dataframes to arrays by [`DataFrame.to_numpy`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html):

```
dfs = [v.to_numpy() for k, v in df.groupby((~df['included']).cumsum()[df['included']])]
print (dfs)
[array([[0.127, True],
       [0.14, True]], dtype=object), array([[0.159, True],
       [0.321, True],
       [0.444, True],
       [0.32299999999999995, True]], dtype=object)]
```